# How to code the cell selection for an input macro that fills cells of an amount predefined by another variable input?

Tags: vba, excel

First of, excuse me that i can't show useful code. I doubt that the pathetic bits I produced in an attempt to solve the problems myself are any help at all, and for other parts I don't even have a clue what commands to use; blame it on my nonexistent experience. All code I can deliver would be what's already working, which doesn't need attention as of now.

I am working on a command button macro for a user interface settings sheet made with excel that is part of a widely customizeable mobile app for Android. A command button for inserting file names by a Windows browser has been successfully implemented, the code can be re-used.

There is just one part of the file left for having buttons to edit it designed. This is how the cells I am describing look like when filled with example names:

[Table with example file names without file extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e95Lv.png)

For better understanding of the whole this is how the buttons are supposed to work in the end. *Parts I am having troubles with will be in bold characters:*

Button #1

- Open an input box for inserting a positive integer value x, return error if input is no positive integer; **save the value safely in a hidden variable for later use**
- **Fill an amount of cells in a column equal to the previous input with numbers counting from one to x**
- For later nice-to-have (optional): **Create a "space" of cells spanning from a specific cell x cells downwards vertically and 3 cells horizontally, where inputs from later prompts are accepted exclusively**

Button #2

- Prompt the user to select a file of a very certain format, put in the file name into a cell (which I already have code for); cancel, but not overwrite if nothing is selected; **Highlight the cell which will be filled by the prompt**
- **Progress to the cell below, open another prompt for filling the cell with the file name string**
- Repeat until the x-th cell is reached
- **Jump to the right neighbor cell of the starting cell**
- Same prompt all the way down to the x-th cell, with another filter
- Jump to second-to-next cell to the right of the start, fill cell with prompt, another filter; every cell of the "space" should be filled by now, if the program is not canceled.

Button #3 (Nice to have)

- Same prompt as above, but not repeated; **apply to active cell**
- **Return error message if a cell outside of the "space" is selected** or multiple cells are selected
- Values of the selected cells are not clobbered if action is canceled

Is there any way to efficiently realize **the highlighted tasks?** I can't find anything working on the net.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. People in here will only be willing to help if you show us some effort, so your code will be required. I suggest reading [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve] help topics

Comment: I wonder if Pseudocode is okay too. I am not familiar with anything beyond the very basics of the possibilities of VBA and know nobody able to help me getting some useful VBA code to start working with done.

Comment: Alright... I hope someone reads this. This is my first question, allready downvoted, most unlikely a lot of people will be looking at it soon, probably should have asked something more simple. So, do you have any _specific_ further suggestions on how to improve this question or should I abandon it and start off with something easier tomorrow? Any help for a newb is appreciated... please.

Comment: I'd try to record some macros to do what you are asking for (since it seems to be too much to work with) and then come back with some code for us to work with. It is nice that you tried to explain everything you are trying to do, but with no code whatsoever it is harder to help you. You say that you "can't produce any code" but then you mentioned you already have some working code in place, so you should review your statements

Comment: Well, the code I already have is kind of a patchwork of snippets I found on the internet and the most simple functions, so it is not really "work of my own"...
Thanks for the feedback, though! I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a satisfying solution working slightly different from what I planned to do in first place, count this question as obsolete.

It involves recycling a browser code I pieced together earlier and a way more specific cell selection than I planned earlier, but it works the originally expressed needs.

Here is the code I produced:

This is basically the main function of planned button #1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    'PreviousNumber saves the value existent before the main program 
    'will run, modified for a function ativated later
    Dim PreviousNumber As String
    PreviousNumber = Range("B11").Value + 14
    'FailSafe is installed for preventing a mismatch
    'error when the following input is cancelled
    Dim FailSafe As Variant
    Dim MyInt As Integer
    FailSafe = InputBox("Wie viele Fragen möchten Sie integrieren?", "Anzahl Fragen", Range("B11").Value)
    If FailSafe = Empty Then
        MyInt = Range("B11").Value
    Else
        MyInt = CInt(FailSafe)
    End If
    Range("B11").Value = MyInt
    'All functions called from here until the end are for
    'actually filling the cells following the input given.
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Counter = 1
    Dim Checker As Boolean
    Checker = True
    Dim SpecifyCell As Integer
    Range("A15:A" & PreviousNumber).Clear
    Do
        If Counter < MyInt Then
            Checker = True
        Else
            Checker = False
        End If
        SpecifyCell = 14 + Counter
        Range("A" & SpecifyCell).Value = Counter
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop While Checker = True
End Sub
```

The following makes planned Buttons #2 and #3 redundant:

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    Dim FailSafe As Variant
    Dim MyInt As Integer
    FailSafe = InputBox("Welche Station möchten Sie bearbeiten?", "Wählen Sie eine Station", 1)
    If FailSafe = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Bitte geben Sie nur eine positive Ganzzahl ein."
    Else
        If CInt(FailSafe) > CInt(Range("B11").Value) Then
            MsgBox "Bitte geben Sie eine Nummer zwischen 1 und der Anzahl der von zu integrieren beabsichtigten Fragen ein."
        Else
            MyInt = CInt(FailSafe)
            MyInt = MyInt + 14
            Browser "PNG", "*.png", "B" & MyInt
            CutPath "B" & MyInt
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Browser and CutPath are the recycled functions mentioned. Browser opens a Windows Browser and enters a file path as a String into variable cells; CutPath takes a value from a cell and deletes everything up to and including the last \ in the String, also cutting of the file extension.

As a result of the heavy dependence on certain cell values, these function put me in need to protect the sheet they are working on.

Summary:

- All primary functions are included and running clean.
- The amount of included buttons will be more than planned, but the total amount won't be too high.
- Most Buttons of the latter type will require multiple clicks in any case.

Comment: That's how you start in programming languages, by researching, collecting useful code online and then, after understanding them, being able to modify them to suit your needs and, in some point in future, start producing your own codes from scratch. Kudos for that and I'm glad you've found something that works for you. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for leaving feedback, I appreciate that!